# Using Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to prove Fatou's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove that all three major theorem in Real Analysis are equivalent, but I don't know how to prove Fatou's Lemma and Monotone Convergence Theorem using Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. For example, can anyone give me a hint on how to prove Fatou's Lemma (or Monotone Convergence Theorem) using Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming LDCT, if you have a monotonically increasing sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$, they are bounded by their limit function. If the limit function is integrable, then you are done.

Comment: What if the limit function is not integrable?

Comment: Then you can't apply LDCT because the dominating function needs to be integrable. Without Fatou's Lemma, I don't see how to prove MCT in the case when the limiting function isn't integrable.

Comment: But if LDCT and MCT (or Fatou's Lemma) are equivalent, then there should be a way to prove MCT by LDCT even when the limit function is not integrable.

Comment: see [here](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/masdoc/people/studentpages/students2014/ozanski/fl_dct_mct.pdf).