# Show $g \in L^1([0,1])$ if a sequence converging to it a.e. is

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^1([0,1])$ such that

$$\vert \vert f_n \vert \vert_1 \leq K$$

for each $n \geq 1$. Prove if $g: [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb{C}$

and $f_n \rightarrow g$ a.e., then $g \in L^1([0,1])$ and that $\vert \vert g \vert \vert_1 \leq K$.

So my thoughts are we have for any given $\epsilon >0$ that there exists an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N$ implies

$$\vert g-f_n \vert < \epsilon$$

Then I can write

\begin{align}
\int_{[0,1]} \vert g  \vert &= \int_{[0,1]} \vert g - f_n \vert + \int_{[0,1]} \vert f_n \vert
\end{align}

where the latter is less than or equal to $K$ and the integrand in the first one on the RHS is less than $\epsilon$? Am I going about this the right way? If not just point me in the right direction please. If so, do I get less than $\epsilon +K$ and as $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we get inequality with $K$, for $g$.

Comment: The problem is that you are assuming uniform convergence a.e. You have for each $x$ there exists $N(x)$ such that $n\geq N(x)\implies |g(x)-f_{n}(x)|<\epsilon$ . Instead what you can do is directly use Fatou's Lemma as I did , or if you want to use MCT then take $h_{n}=\inf_{k\geq n} f_{k}$ . This is an increasing sequence which converges to $g$ if you don't want to directly use Fatou's Lemma. Anyways this does assume MCT . You will see that MCT and Fatou's are equivalent . That is one can be proven assuming the other. Also MCT is also proven independently as in Stein Shakarchi.

Comment: Ah, so what I have is just point wise convergence, not uniform (which I incorrectly assumed). And yes, Fatou's Lemma and MCT can prove each other, I recently discovered this fact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatou's Lemma gives you that

$$\int_{[0,1]}|g|\leq \lim\inf\int_{[0,1]} |f_{n}| \leq  K$$

Comment: I was trying to do so without the use of Fatou's Lemma. But yes, this works!

Comment: Ah! In that case you can look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114458/proving-fatous-lemma-from-the-dct).